# Custom IDs in ListView

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to populate a listview with products. I can do it, but I need them to have custom id's (the ones from the SQLite database). How can I do this? This is my code without the id implementation so far:

```
ArrayList<String> productNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> productIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor results = myDbHelper.getProducts();
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productlist);

    while (results.moveToNext()){
        productNameList.add(results.getString(results.getColumnIndex("name")));
        productIdList.add(results.getString(results.getColumnIndex("id")));
    }


    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , productNameList));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
    String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "name" };
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, columns, to);
    lv.setAdapter(mAdapter));
```

"to" and "columns" define a mapping:
"colums" is a list of the database column names you want the SimpleCursorAdapter to read. And "to" is a list of android ids specifying on which widget the values from the cursor are set.

In the latter code this means that the value of "_id" will be displayed in the textfield with the android id  "android.R.id.text1" and the value of the column "name" will go into textfield "android.R.id.text2".

Comment: What does the "to" do and what is my_cell_layout? Thanks.